# How to make Smooth Freehand drawing in ios?

Tags: ios, drawing, core-animation, core-graphics

I followed [THIS](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/ios-sdk_freehand-drawing/) tutorial and i have two problems:

1. How to change the color of line when we are drawing it (not when drawing finished)?
2. How to round the ends of lines?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use any of these nice examples :

1. [Paint Pad](http://code4app.net/ios/Paint-Pad/4fcf74876803faec66000000)
2. [My-Palette](http://code4app.net/ios/My-Palette/509771406803faca4f000000)
3. [Drawing-View](http://code4app.net/ios/Drawing-View/50f777ff6803fab458000000)
4. [ACEDrawingView](https://github.com/acerbetti/ACEDrawingView)
5. [smooth-line-drawing-in-ios](http://tonyngo.net/2011/09/smooth-line-drawing-in-ios/)

Hope these helps you.